# Saving of multi-polygon shapefile into a individual polygon shapefiles

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.0

How to separate a multi-polygon shapefile into individual polygons (as separate shapefiles)? I had huge data...
I know the traditional process like export data...

Please help me...

Comment: It's not completely clear what the desired result should be. Should it be one shapefile for each original multipolygon? One Shapefile for each processed polygon? Some other rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 tools in arcgis.

1. The [multipart to single part too](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Multipart_To_Singlepart/00170000003r000000/)l in toolbox.
2. The [explode](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Separating_a_multipart_feature_Explode/01m800000002000000/) tool on the advanced editing toolbar.

Comment: Does the Explode tool make individual shapefiles? or just individual shapes?

Comment: It works inside of an edit session with only the selected objects. It makes single shapes of multi. You can set the split rules so it will follow rules on split.

Answer (score 4):

First step using QGIS, you have to divide the multipolygon to individual polygins with `Vector->Geometry Tools->Multipart to single parts`

Then you have to edit the attribute table to give all objects a unique number.

With that, you can use the `Shapefile splitter` plugin to dissolve the shapefile with several objects into several shapefiles with just one object.